# Revit addins Window stops responding after family upgrade

Tags: wpf, revit-api

Ok, I have a strange situation with an add-in for Revit.  The add-in uses a non-modal window that lists things out and among them are families.  The user can choose a family to load and it then fires an external event that handles loading the family and prompting for placement.

All of this works fine, but if the family is not current (i.e. needs to be upgraded) it causes the UI not to update afterward.  The standard Revit upgrade dialog shows up and then goes away and the user is prompted for placement of the family, but if they go back to the dialog nothing updates.

IMPORTANT NOTE: This is NOT a frozen UI issue or a locked thread.  I can drag the window around, and if I click on any of the links in the UI that are supposed to open web pages or external sources the external sources open, so it is actually processing clicks, etc.  However, when I do something that should make changes to the UI (like mouse over a button or try to click a filtering button) nothing changes.

To make it even stranger, if I click the link on the dialog that should bring up the 'About' dialog it comes up... and then the main UI updates and is working properly again.  When the UI updates it updates to show as it should be based on the clicks I made while it was not updating so obviously it was processing correctly it just wasn't updating the dialog UI.

So it seems like this is some type of redraw issue and it seems to be triggered by the family upgrade dialog.  I'm at a loss how to debug this though.  How would I go about either debugging this or forcing a redraw or...?

Any advice is much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Here is the method code for showing the non-modal dialog (can be started at any time).  This just shows the window where the user can invoke the family load (among other things):

```
//If we have a window then it's shown, just activate it for the user and return
if (_window != null)
{
    _window.Activate();
    return;
}

//Don't have a window, check if we have a model (model is cached, window is not)
if (_vm == null)
{
    //Construct a new model
    _vm = new ToolboxVM(_cacheManager, _contentProviderService, _updatesService, _settingManager,
        _imageCache);
    _vm.StartContent += (sender, content) => ExecuteContent?.Invoke(content);
}
else
{
    //We need to clear the filters, otherwise the model is filtered but the UI doesn't show it.
    _vm.ContentTypeFilter.Clear();
    _vm.IndustryFilter.Clear();
}

//Now create a window and show it
_window = new Wnd_Toolbox() {DataContext = _vm};
var unused = new WindowInteropHelper(_window) {Owner = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle};
_window.Closed += (sender, e) => _window = null;
_window.Show();
```

When the user presses the button to load content it invokes this method:

```
try
{
    if (Utility.CacheableTypes.Contains(cp.ContentType) && _cacheManager.GetCachedVersion(cp) == null)
        _cacheManager.DownloadToCache(cp);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(
        "There was an error caching the content, content could not be started:\n\n" + ex.Message, "Error",
        MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    return;
}

StartContent?.Invoke(this, cp);
```

The last line of this event invokes the 'StartContent' event.  That just bubbles up into the Revit implementation and from there invokes an External Event in Revit for loading the family.  Here is the code for the family portion of the external event handler:

```
Family fam;
using (var t = new Transaction(app.ActiveUIDocument.Document, "Load Family"))
{
    if (t.Start() != TransactionStatus.Started)
        throw new Exception("The transaction failed to start, could not load family.");

    app.ActiveUIDocument.Document
       .LoadFamily(ContentUtility.GetLocalCacheLocation(ExecutingContent, true), out fam);

    t.Commit();
}

if (fam != null)
{
    var symbol =
        (FamilySymbol) app.ActiveUIDocument.Document.GetElement(fam.GetFamilySymbolIds()
            .FirstOrDefault());
    if (symbol != null) app.ActiveUIDocument.PostRequestForElementTypePlacement(symbol);
}
```

Comment: You sure you have opened a transaction?

Comment: Positive.  Plus everything in Revit works fine it's just the UI that doesn't refresh on my dialog.  Plus if Revit doesn't have to upgrade then the issue doesn't happen.

Comment: Can you post some code snippets where events happen, like opening the form, committing the transaction

Comment: Added code to the question.